# How to open terminal window and application in tkinter window?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am able to open a terminal window inside of a tkinter window with the following code:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=400, width=500)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 40x20 -sb &' % wid  )

root.mainloop()
```

But I need it to open AND run a command like

```
  sudo certbot --nginx
```

So the window opens to this running without having to type it in.

Here is what I have tried that didn't work:

```
from tkinter import *
import os

root = Tk()
termf = Frame(root, height=400, width=500)

termf.pack(fill=BOTH, expand=YES)
wid = termf.winfo_id()
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 40x20 -sb &' % wid " | sudo certbot --nginx" )

root.mainloop()
```

So essentially I want to create a button that once clicked, opens a terminal window inside the tkinter window, and automatically runs the certbot command.

Comment: Is there a reason you want to run `sudo certbot --nginx` *inside* a terminal within tk? If you're just interested in the output of the command, you could try using the `subprocess` module.

Comment: Try `os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 40x20 -sb -e "sudo certbot --nginx"' % wid)` instead.

Comment: well I want my application to be able to apply a certificate to their site via certbot, and do not know how to feed the prompts from certbot to my tkinter app for a user input.  So I thought maybe just run it in a separate window and the users can follow the prompts.  If you could show me how to feed the prompt from certbot to a tkinter entry, I'd be greatly appreciative and would be able to repeat it for the rest of the prompts.

Comment: @AlberNovo that didn't work. :(

Answer (score 1):

This actually did it:

```
os.system('xterm -into %d -geometry 82x20  -e sudo certbot --nginx &' % wid )
```